# SQLite error (1): near "=": syntax error

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have syntax error with SQLiteDatabase.

Here, my script for create my table :

```
CREATE TABLE `plan` (
  refPlan TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  label TEXT NOT NULL,
  dateCreation date NOT NULL,
  dateModification date NOT NULL,
  refProjet TEXT NOT NULL,
  typeCouverture TEXT NOT NULL,
  id_coupe int NOT NULL,
  typePlancher TEXT NOT NULL,
  nomGamme TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (refProjet) REFERENCES projet,
  FOREIGN KEY (typeCouverture) REFERENCES couverture,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_coupe) REFERENCES coupePrincipe,
  FOREIGN KEY (typePlancher) REFERENCES plancher,
  FOREIGN KEY (nomGamme) REFERENCES gamme
);
```

Here is my request :

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM `plan` WHERE refProjet = 'PRO001'";
```

And, the error :

```
SQLite error (1): near "=": syntax error
Une exception de première chance de type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' s'est produite dans System.Data.SQLite.dll
```

Can anybody help me, please ?

Comment: Why is table name plan with apostrophe

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I have see one time that plan is reserved by sqlite, so I thought to do well if I have used a backquote to avoid possible error..

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I have a same error with that : SQLQuery = "SELECT refPlan, label, dateCreation, dateModification, refProjet, typePlancher, typeCouverture, id_coupe, nomGamme FROM plan WHERE refProjet = '" + projet.reference + "'";

Comment: The query looks OK. There might be some hidden control character or something like that, but it's not possible to determine this from the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command inside double quote

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM [plan] WHERE refProjet = 'PRO001'";
```